# What is the difference between reboot and shutdown -r?

Tags: shutdown, reboot

The title says it all: What is the difference between executing `shutdown -r` and `reboot`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nothing, both of them do the same task.

From the respective man pages:

[man `reboot`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot%E2%80%8E):

```
reboot, halt, poweroff

These programs allow a system administrator to reboot, halt or poweroff the system.
```

[man `shutdown -r`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown):

```
Requests that the system be rebooted after it has  been brought down.
```

Without the `-f` option for `reboot`, it will gracefully terminate all processes, sending signal 15. However, using `reboot -f` will invoke the  `reboot(2)` system call itself (with `REBOOTCOMMAND` argument passed) and directly reboots the  system.

---

From [a similar question on Unix and linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now):

Internally, `reboot` uses `shutdown -r`.

Comment: Will they both reboot the system after gracefully stopping running services? I usually user reboot, but I have a concern that it terminates running processes.

Comment: Answered your comment in the answer, please have a look.

Comment: according to [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot), `reboot` calls `shutdown` by default, which shuts down the computer nicely. With the right flag, you can force `reboot` to use `halt` instead. The shut down is the done the violent way. EDIT: Didn't see the answer was updated to address this. I'll keep the comment for the link

Comment: Then why can my system froze by the reboot command and why not when I use 'shutdown -r now'?